# Merging Memory Streams to create a http PDF response in c#

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, crystal-reports, itext

I am trying to merge 2 crystal reports into single pdf file  and I'm using Itextsharp v5.1.1. But it says the document cannot be opened. It might be corrupted. There are no build errors. but the pdf is malformed and cant be opened. Here is the order I chose to accomplish this.

1. Export the Crystal report to MemoryStream1 in pdf format
2. Export the second report into MemoryStream2.
3. Merge the Memory Streams
4. Send the Streams to Http Output Response as PDF.

Here is the Code for each step in the order.

```
   /// Get the Dataset from Stored Procedure for the CSSource Report
   dsCS = CSData.GetUSSourceXML(ds_input);
   /// Create the Report of type CSsource
   rptCS = ReportFactory.GetReport(typeof(CSsource));
   rptCS .SetDataSource(dsCS);
   /// Set the Parameters to the CS report
   rptCS .ParameterFields["Parameterid"].CurrentValues.Clear();
   rptCS .SetParameterValue("Parameterid", PID);
   //// Serialize the Object as PDF                    
   msCS=(MemoryStream)rptCS .ExportToStream(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
```

For Step 2

```
   /// Get the Dataset from Stored Procedure for the Aden Report
   dsAd = CSData.GetAdden(ds_input);
   /// Create the Report of type Aden
   rptAd = ReportFactory.GetReport(typeof(Aden));
   rptAd.SetDataSource(dsAd );
   /// Set the Parameters to the Aden report
   rptAd.ParameterFields["Parameterid"].CurrentValues.Clear();
   rptAd.SetParameterValue("Parameterid", PID);
   //// Serialize the Object as PDF                    
   msAD = (MemoryStream)rptAd.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
```

For Step 3

```
  System.Collections.Generic.List<byte[]> sourceFiles = new List<byte[]>();
  sourceFiles.Add(msCS.ToArray());
  sourceFiles.Add(msAD.ToArray());
  PdfMerger mpdfs = new PdfMerger();
  /// ms is the Memory stream to which both the streams are added
  ms=mpdfs.MergeFiles(sourceFiles);
```

MergeFiles method is as follows

```
 public MemoryStream MergeFiles(Generic.List<byte[]> sourceFiles)
    {
        Document document = new Document();
        MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();

        try
        {
            // Initialize pdf writer
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);
            //writer.PageEvent = new PdfPageEvents();

            // Open document to write
            document.Open();
            PdfContentByte content = writer.DirectContent;

            // Iterate through all pdf documents
            for (int fileCounter = 0; fileCounter < sourceFiles.Count; 
                   fileCounter++)
            {
                // Create pdf reader
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(sourceFiles[fileCounter]);
                int numberOfPages = reader.NumberOfPages;

                // Iterate through all pages
                for (int currentPageIndex = 1; currentPageIndex <=
                                   numberOfPages; currentPageIndex++)
                {
                    // Determine page size for the current page
                    document.SetPageSize(
                       reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(currentPageIndex));

                    // Create page
                    document.NewPage();
                    PdfImportedPage importedPage =
                      writer.GetImportedPage(reader, currentPageIndex);


                    // Determine page orientation
                    int pageOrientation = 
                      reader.GetPageRotation(currentPageIndex);
                    if ((pageOrientation == 90) || (pageOrientation == 270))
                    {
                     content.AddTemplate(importedPage, 0, -1f, 1f, 0, 0,
                     reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(currentPageIndex).Height);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    content.AddTemplate(importedPage, 1f, 0, 0, 1f, 0, 0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
        throw new Exception("There has an unexpected exception" +
        " occured during the pdf merging process.", exception);
        }
        finally
        {
           // document.Close();
        }
        return output;
    }
```

Step 4 to Serialize the Memory stream as PDF

```
  // ms is the memory stream which is to be converted to PDF
  Response.Clear();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.Charset = string.Empty;
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", 
        "attachment; filename=" + 
        "Application of " + FullName.Trim() + ".pdf");
        //Write the file directly to the HTTP content output stream.
        Response.OutputStream.Write(ms.ToArray(), 0, 
               Convert.ToInt32(ms.Length));
        Response.OutputStream.Flush();
        Response.OutputStream.Close();
        rptCS.Close();
        rptCS.Dispose();
        rptAd.Close();
        rptAd.Dispose();
```

Thanks for all those Developers helping me with this.
This is Urgent because it has to go production in a day or 2. 
Please respond.

Chandanan.

Comment: did you check whether each pdf itself is ok ?

Comment: Yes they are working separately with the merge function commented out. I could see each of the report.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a simple merge method that copies PDF files into one PDF.  I use this method quite often when merging pdfs. Hope it helps.

```
    public MemoryStream MergePdfForms(List<byte[]> files)
    {
        if (files.Count > 1)
        {
            PdfReader pdfFile;
            Document doc;
            PdfWriter pCopy;
            MemoryStream msOutput = new MemoryStream();

            pdfFile = new PdfReader(files[0]);

            doc = new Document();
            pCopy = new PdfSmartCopy(doc, msOutput);

            doc.Open();

            for (int k = 0; k < files.Count; k++)
            {
                pdfFile = new PdfReader(files[k]);
                for (int i = 1; i < pdfFile.NumberOfPages + 1; i++)
                {
                    ((PdfSmartCopy)pCopy).AddPage(pCopy.GetImportedPage(pdfFile, i));
                }
                pCopy.FreeReader(pdfFile);
            }

            pdfFile.Close();
            pCopy.Close();
            doc.Close();

            return msOutput;
        }
        else if (files.Count == 1)
        {
            return new MemoryStream(files[0]);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Step 4 try:

```
        rptCS.Close();
        rptCS.Dispose();
        rptAd.Close();
        rptAd.Dispose();

        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", 
    "attachment; filename=" + 
    "Application of " + FullName.Trim() + ".pdf");
        Response.BinaryWrite(ms.ToArray());
        ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

Comment: Jonathan, thanks for the reply. I used the above code but I still dont think this helped. The error that I came accross is 'Cannot open a closed stream'. Then I commented 3 lines of code in the above function as follows. //pdfFile.Close();//pCopy.Close();//doc.Close(); Then there is no runtime error and then I could save a file. but when I opened it, it is blank as usual and corrupted. What version of Itextsharp are you using? I am using the latest 5.1.1 version. I can try using your version with your code. Thanks so much.

Comment: @Chandanan I use itextsharp 5.1.0 and that shoudn't be the issue with your code.  I'm thinking you may have an issue with step 4. see my edit.

Comment: Jonathan, I could get this work!!! Thanks man, Just a little change in the sequence that I did.  Just reordered the 4th step and put these 4 lines in the bottom and it worked. rptCS.Close(); rptCS.Dispose();   rptAd.Close();           rptAd.Dispose();  Thanks a ton man. :)

Comment: This is life saver. Thank you.