# IText add new page to existing pdf with PDF Reader

Tags: jsf, pdf, itext

What I am trying to do is add a new page to the end of the current pdf that I am editing right after `setFields()` method. I am getting it with `PdfReader` and never have a Document object so I am not sure how I would do this. Here are the two methods that are creating the PDF.

Edit :

Upon further investigation I found that you can insert a page with stamper.insertPage. But This seems to be a little too hard to do what I want with it. Is there a way to just merge two pdf's with `acrofields` together? And by merge I mean the first pdf have 2 pages and the second pdf have 1 page and put them together and now the pdf has 3 pages.

```
public static void createPdf(MyDocument document) {
    try {
        PdfReader pdfTemplate = initPdfReader();

        if (pdfTemplate != null) {
            OutputStream output = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponseOutputStream();

            PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfTemplate, output);
            stamper.setFormFlattening(true);

            AcroFields fields = stamper.getAcroFields();
            setFields(document, fields, stamper);

            stamper.close();
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        BeanUtils.addMessage(new Message("An error has occurred while crating PDF.:" + ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e)));
        LOG.error(e);
    }
}
```

InitPdfReader()

```
public static PdfReader initPdfReader() throws Exception {
    PdfReader pdfReader = null;
    InputStream inStream = null;

    try {
        ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();

        ec.responseReset();
        ec.setResponseContentType("pdf");
        ec.setResponseHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + "FileName" + "\"");

        inStream = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream("/resources/documents/MyDocument.pdf");
        pdfReader = new PdfReader(inStream);
        pdfReader.close();
    } finally {
        if (inStream != null) {
            inStream.close();
        }
    }
    return pdfReader;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the Pdf*Copy* classes?

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of [iTextSharp adding new instances of an existing page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23726947/itextsharp-adding-new-instances-of-an-existing-page) You need to use `PdfCopy` and the `setMergeFields()` method (a method that is often forgotten).